# Moving duplicates in a Pandas dataframe to a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to sort through a pandas dataframe and find duplicates.

[image]

However, I am not just trying to locate duplicates and get rid of them. I need to see exactly which two(or more) file numbers contain the same EIN, and move that over to a new data frame.

For example, if file_num 376, and 7212 contain the exact same EIN (12370123723), I'd like to create a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
EIN:            file_num
12370123723     376, 7212
```

If anyone has any suggestions as to how to do something like this, any feedback would be appreciated. I tried using the .duplicated() method, but this only returns Bools and doesn't tell me exactly which files are duplicates of which.

Comment: `df.groupby('EIN')['file_num'].agg(list)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following:

```
dups = df[df.EIN.duplicated(keep=False)]
dups.groupby("EIN")["file_num"].apply(list)
```

These are the results for synthetic data:

Data:

```
   EIN  file_num
0    2         0
1    5         1
2    0         2
3    5         3
4    5         4
5    5         5
6    6         6
7    0         7
8    2         8
9    3         9
```

Output:

```
EIN
0          [2, 7]
2          [0, 8]
5    [1, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: if it answers your question, it would be great if you could accept my answer for future generations (click the grey checkmark next to the answer, turning it from grey to green).

Comment: Absolutely, it just made me wait a few minutes before I could accept the answer. Thanks!